# Visual Studio will automatically make functional changes to the following projects in order to open them

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, decompiling

I decompiled a EXE and now when I try to open it. I get

```
One-way upgrade
Visual Studio will automatically make functional changes to the following projects in order to open them. You will not be able to open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
```

If I click okay I get ~250 errors

I found that need to open .csproj file and delete lines with 
ProjectMode, TargetOfficeVersion, FileUpgradeFlags, UpgradeBackupLocation or OldToolsVersion. But I don't have in .csproj any lines like this.

Is there a way to fix this. Or at least a way to find what Version of Visual Studio was using the author ?

Comment: If you open the solution file, the file version is usually in the first few lines.

Comment: @Neil When I open .csproj file with text editor I see this line  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>               I'm using VS Studio 2017. What visual studio I need to use to open the project ?

Comment: Is there a solution (.sln) file too?

Comment: @Neil Okay. I find it Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008

Comment: .NET 3.5 was released in 2007, and the nearest Visual Studio is 2008, so I would try that.